# Zooming in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: compiz, accessibility, zooming

I love the goals of Ubuntu, and have tried it and other distros based on it several times over the last five years.  It's amazing how far the desktop environment has come and how easy it is to set up ,but I am still extremely disappointed in the accessibility for people who are visually impaired.   Orca is a joke.  The magnifier wouldn't be good even if it were stable.  I found Vinux the other day, and found that they had another solution that involves compiz. They have a button to activate compiz and then all you have to do is press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> click to zoom in.  It works great.  But I'm having other hardware and network problems.  Can you help me get similar functionality in Ubuntu?

I know nothing about how to get to anything or do anything in the new version.  I can follow instructions and navigate the system using the terminal.

Comment: I found something called "kmag" for Ubuntu, but I tried to install it using USC , and resulted as untrusted application, i quit installing from there. please help me in Kmag

Answer (score 0):

The OP answered in a comment:

> I answered my own question.  To get this working, I installed the
>   CompizConfig Settings Manager from the Ubuntu software center.  From
>   the dash I searched for the program after it was downloaded.  I went
>   to enhanced zoom desktop and enabled zoom in with the mouse pic next
>   to it and set the key binding to super plus button 1 (the left mouse
>   button)  and then I enabled zoom out with the mouse pic next to it and
>   set the key binding to super plus button 3 (the right mouse button). 
>   I hope this helps anyone else who is having this problem.  Can we make
>   this a little easier for legally blind people?

– [Ross](/users/88217/ross) Sep 7 '1. at 23:03

Comment: what is 'xzoom' in this case?